# Programming for GPS Navigator Devices and RFID Reader?

Tags: navigation, geolocation, gps, device, rfid

I want to program to integrate this 2 devices GPS Device and RFID. To show a map that have direction to navigate user to destination that input from RFID Card.

What devices or platform that I should use?

Answer (score 2):

A great platform for this kind of prototype is [arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/). Arduino is opensource hardware, there are several addon boards (called shields) providing GPS and RFID.